# Check for evenness of all digits

Tags: php

How can I check whether all the digits of an integer are even?

Example

```
$a = 22444648;
$b = 324687;
```

All digits of `$a` are even: 2%2==0, 4%2==0... so I want to return true. On the other hand, `$b` ought to return false, because 3%2!=0.

Comment: `$hasAllEvens = (boolean) preg_match('/^[02468]+$/', $a);` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_split($integer)` to split your integer into an array of digits. You can then iterate through the array elements, and return false as soon as you encounter a digit that is not even.

```
function isEven($integer){
    $digits = str_split($integer);

    foreach($digits as $digit){
        if($digit % 2 != 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: $array = str_split($a);
foreach($array as $val){
 if($val%2==0){
  return true;
 }else{
  $return false;
 }
}

something like that... but it wont work :(

Comment: It won't work if you return true as soon as you encounter an even number, otherwise you'll end up not checking all the remaining numbers.

Comment: And how can i do that...?

Comment: I've editted my answer. This is a basic problem ..

Comment: This function won't check my all values from array if they are even or not...

Comment: What do you mean? It goes through the digits one by one, and if they're all even it will return true at the end. As soon as it encounters a digit that is not even, it will return false.

Comment: My bad. It works. sorry :) And thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question has many possible solutions - If you're looking for a one-liner, you can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if the integer contains all even values.

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

A regex of `/^[02468]+$/` should return `1` if all values are even, or `0` (or `false` otherwise). Then it's simply a case of casting that result to a `boolean`; i.e:

```
$a = 224455;
$hasAllEvens = (boolean) preg_match('/^[02468]+$/', $a);
```

I'd recommend testing this as per your specific use-case. For instance do you have to support negative numbers? Or, are padded numbers acceptable; e.g: `0024` or even `00000`?

Since there are many possibly solutions, you can have have some fun with alternatives. Here's a more involved example:

```
<?php

// split the integer into an array and 
// apply a reduce function over each element.
// 
// this function applies a bitwise AND where 
// the left-hand value is 1, and the right-hand
// value is a single digit integer. an operation
// with an even number returns `0` and an operation
// with an odd number returns `1`. this result is 
// added to the `carry` value, which is the result
// of the previously applied function.
// 
// once iteration is complete, the resulting value
// is `0` is all integers were even, and a value
// greater than `0` representing a "count" of any
// odd values encountered.
//
// finally we negate this value to cast to 
// a boolean to get our final result.

function hasAllEvens($int)
{
    return !array_reduce(str_split($int), function ($carry, $item) {
        return (1 & $item) + $carry;
    });
}

// and a quick test... 
// any number that has at least one 
// odd integer will return false.

foreach (range(0, 21) as $int) {
    $result = hasAllEvens($int) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    printf("hasAllEvens(%d) -> %s\n", $int, $result);
}
```

Yields:

```
hasAllEvens(0) -> yes
hasAllEvens(1) -> no
hasAllEvens(2) -> yes
hasAllEvens(3) -> no
hasAllEvens(4) -> yes
hasAllEvens(5) -> no
hasAllEvens(6) -> yes
hasAllEvens(7) -> no
hasAllEvens(8) -> yes
hasAllEvens(9) -> no
hasAllEvens(10) -> no
hasAllEvens(11) -> no
hasAllEvens(12) -> no
hasAllEvens(13) -> no
hasAllEvens(14) -> no
hasAllEvens(15) -> no
hasAllEvens(16) -> no
hasAllEvens(17) -> no
hasAllEvens(18) -> no
hasAllEvens(19) -> no
hasAllEvens(20) -> yes
hasAllEvens(21) -> no
```

And so on.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I like the `preg_match` approach :-)

Comment: Thanks, same here :) Shortest solution is usually the best!